# Posting tweets from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, twitter

How could I post custom tweets on my twitter account using vb.net?

If is not possible, which I doubt, is there any way to achive this with c# or javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/) library.

---

Here's an example how to use it:

```
Dim tokens As New OAuthTokens()
tokens.AccessToken = "XXX"
tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "XXX"
tokens.ConsumerKey = "XXX"
tokens.ConsumerSecret = "XXX"

Dim tweetResponse As TwitterResponse(Of TwitterStatus) = TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, "Hello, #Twitterizer")

If tweetResponse.Result = RequestResult.Success Then
        ' Tweet posted successfully!
Else
        ' Something bad happened
End If
```

---

BTW, [here's a list of avaiable twitter libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#dotnet) (but it's not 100% up-to-date).

Comment: From where should I get the tokens?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in LINQ to Twitter like this:

```
    Dim credentials As IOAuthCredentials = New InMemoryCredentials
    credentials.ConsumerKey = "xxx"
    credentials.ConsumerSecret = "xxx"
    credentials.OAuthToken = "xxx"
    credentials.AccessToken = "xxx"

    Dim auth As PinAuthorizer = New PinAuthorizer()
    auth.Credentials = credentials

    Dim twitterCtx As TwitterContext = New TwitterContext(auth)
    twitterCtx.UpdateStatus(statusMsg)
```

and if you want to perform a query, you can do it like this:

```
    Dim queryResults = _
        From search In twitterCtx.Search _
        Where search.Type = SearchType.Search _
        And search.Query = "LINQ to Twitter"
```

More info here: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

A super easy way of doing this is by using [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) and my [IFTTT Maker.net libary](http://www.mediafire.com/download/39vn1rx0e5tix2y/ifttt.vb)

First, in IFTTT create a new recipe that's triggered by the Maker channel and name the event "tweet_now".

Then, select the Twitter engine and click "Post a tweet", remove everything from the input box and replace it with {{value1}} and click create recipe.

After that, in Visual studio, add ifttt.vb to your project. Now for the code:

```
      Try
    makechannel.scode = "your account ID"
    makechannel.fireevent("tweet_now", "Tweet text", "", "")
   'code goes here if done
    Catch ex As Exception
        'code goes here if it fails
    End Try
```

Then fill in your account ID. You can find it at ifttt.com/maker

And that's it!